# how to know qml item is visual or resource?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qt-quick

Suppose I have a *qml* with Item as root and 2 visual(Text, Rectangle) and one non-visual item(Timer). I know i can use "*data*" to get the list of visual and non visual items, but **how to identify visual and non visual items while iterating**,?

Note: I can specify a naming convention while create each item, but is there any property/API is available to identify visual and non-visual items?

```
Item {
    children: [
        Text {},
        Rectangle {}
    ]
    resources: [
        Timer {}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that ?
Use data to assign elements, and then you can iterate over the visual ones with children, or the non visual ones with resources.

Answer (score 3):

All visual items are derived from `Item` so they will all have the corresponding properties. You can do something as basic as:

```
var obj = data[i]
if (obj.visible !== undefined) // obj has visible property so it is a visual item
```

Naturally, if for some reason you have a custom type which is not a visual item but for some reason has a `visible` property, this won't work, so pick the property accordingly.

Comment: Maybe `instanceof` can be used to be more robust than blindingly checking for properties?